# Tengo un problema con mis @view child

Tags: angular

Mis importaciones

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; 
import { People } from '../people.model';
```

Mi componente

```
@Output() peopleCreate = new EventEmitter<People>();   
// nameInput:String;   
// lastNameInput:String;   
@ViewChild('lastNameInput') lastNameInput: ElementRef;  
@ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput: ElementRef;
```

El error se presenta en la delcaracion de los `@ViewChild`

Comment: Hola, Te recomiendo leer como preguntar primero (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) , Que problema tienes con los @ViewChild ?  que has intentado hasta el momento ?

Comment: si me mando un error ya estoy investigando el error tambien ya tengo declara la de view child en los import

Comment: @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput: ElementRef;

Comment: este en la linea qie tengo mal

Comment: Pero que estas tratando de hacer con el @ViewChild ? ,  por que es el error ? ..... que te dice el error ?, estas tratando de recibir o enviar datos entre componentes o que ?

Comment: Si estas utilizando la ultima version de angular debes declarar el view child asi:  `@ViewChild('botonBasicoSiguiente', { static: true }) private botonBasicoSiguiente: ElementRef;`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me quedo si era eso por que tengo la ultima version gracias  Bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando la ultima version de angular debes declarar el view child asi:

```
@ViewChild('botonBasicoSiguiente', { static: true }) private botonBasicoSiguiente: ElementRef;
```